# Using Apache Commons File Upload

Tags: java, apache, file-upload, ftp

I am trying to upload a pdf file to ftp server. My code is somewhat like this:

```
public void pdfUpload(String ticket, JLabel message) {     

FTPClient client = new FTPClient(); 
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            client.connect("www.mydomain.com", 21);
            client.login("user", "userpass");


            client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE); // optional


            String FileName = ticket.replace("/", "_");
            File fil = new File("pdf\\"+FileName+".pdf");
            message.setText(FileName+".pdf is being uploaded... Please wait" );
            fis = new FileInputStream(fil);

            String remoteFile = fil.getName();
            client.storeFile(remoteFile, fis);
            client.logout();
            message.setText("File Uploaded sccessfully");
        } 

        catch (IOException e) {
            message.setText("Failed to upload pdf file"+e);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fis != null) {
                    fis.close();
                }
                client.disconnect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            message.setText("Failed to upload pdf file");
            }
        }    
}
```

The method shows that the file is uploaded, The method executes fine. and shows the completion message. But I cannot find the file in ftp. It means the file is not uploaded. What is wrong with my code. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling enterLocalPassiveMode after login.

It could be many things, as FTP servers are unpredictable little monsters, but that's what it smells like to me.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like your File path would be valid on the remote system as a file name, or it isn't storing it as expected based upon the file path name format. Try using just the file name without the "pdf\\" prefix when saving to the remote system.